# One hour less when saving django datetimefield

Tags: django, datetime, timezone, fullcalendar, pytz

When saving the following model, the start datetime is saved with one hour less than my localtime. I have set `USE_TZ = True` and `TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Madrid"`. I suppose that hour less is because it is referred to UTC (one hour less than Europe/Madrid). MySQL stores the wrong datetime too. However, I need to display the correct datetime in my website. The datetime is correct in the admin, but not in the rest of the application.

I have tried by several ways to implement the datetime, but I can't get it. This is my actual code, assigned to the start field:

```
pytz.timezone("Europe/Madrid").localize(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

When I execute the previous instruction, I get the correct date with `print`, but when saved, it is stored with one hour less. Why?

This is my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    start       = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end         = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    allday      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Edit-1:

The AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/projects/{{project.id}}/get_events/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            data = eval("(" + response + ")")

            var events = [];

            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                events.push({
                        id: data[i].pk,
                        title: data[i].fields['title'],
                        start: data[i].fields['start'],
                        end: data[i].fields['end'],
                        className: "event",
                        defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:30:00"
                });
            }
        }
 });
```

Comment: Have you read the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)? The datetime is stored in UTC because aware datetimes are *always* stored in UTC. The timezone that is displayed to the user, though, is based on the current time zone, which by default is the `TIME_ZONE` timezone. That's why you get the right value in the admin. Please define "the rest of the application" so it's clear exactly where you're getting the wrong value.

Comment: With "the rest of the application" I mean the website. I have a calendar plugin and every event displayed in it has one hour less (the UTC datetime). How can I refer to the localtime or current time zone instead of the datetime stored in UTC?

Comment: I'm getting all the calendar events by an AJAX call, querying the events with a simple 'events = Event.objects.filter(user=user)' and serializing them 'data = serializers.serialize('json', events)'. I put the AJAX call in the edit section of the post.

Comment: Are you using Django's built-in serialization, or a framework like Tastypie or Django-REST-Framework?

Comment: Built-in serialization, `from django.core import serializers`.

Comment: It looks like Django doesn't convert `datetimes` to the current timezone before serialization. I can think of a few options: 1) If you only ever care about your local time zone, you can set `USE_TZ` to `False`. 2) You can customize serialization (whether in Django itself or in one of the frameworks mentioned above) to convert the value before serializaing it. 3) You can do the conversion in javascript on the client.

Comment: do you have `USE_TZ = True` in your settings?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was with the calendar plugin (FullCalendar), and not with the entire application. I have realized that FullCalendar has a timezone option, which was set to false. Setting it to "local", datetimes are displayed correctly in the website.

Anyway, thanks you all for your help!